# How to export an animation to my sprite engine

Tags: animation, blend-files

I have a blender animation for use in a multi platform app. The sprite engine is Urhosharp. 
In urho, an animation has a defined animated object with the meshes of several bones, and a texture direct draw surface.
How should I convert my animation to try to make it useable in urho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a blender plugin that can export *.ani animations to Urho 3d.
View the Github repository of [reattiva](https://github.com/reattiva/Urho3D-Blender).